# Facing Issue to delete ibm db2 on cloud service

Tags: ibm-cloud

By mistake I have activated IBM DB2 on Cloud service , but when I m trying to delete , it's not getting deleted , is there any way to delete it?

Comment: Your question is not clear, but it sounds like a support issue. Please contact IBM support.

Comment: As @data_henrik suggested, please open a ticket with Bluemix Support. You can click the Support link in the Bluemix UI to submit a ticket. Alternatively, you can submit a ticket through this link: https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp/